# Summing the values of one element of a dictionary based upon the values of another element

Tags: python, dictionary

Using Python, I have a list of two-element dictionaries which I would like to sum all the values of one element based upon the values of another element. ie.

```
[{'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.52355755017894}, {'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.5235575501288667}]
```

This is the format (although there are much more entries than this), and for each different `elev` I would like to have the sum of all the `area` values that correspond to it.  For the `elev` value of `0.0` I would like the sum of all values, same for `elev` of `0.1` etc

Comment: Hello, did you try something ?

Comment: Yes I tried a for loop within a for loop, to iterate over the elev values and compare them to a new dictionary which would store just the elevation and the accumulation of the total area for that elev.. But it didn't work at all and just returned an empty list

Comment: You can make another dictionary where first item would be value of elev and second would be sum of all areas corresponding to that particular elev value. Now just iterate through your original list and modify your resulting list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very easily achieved using pandas. Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.52355755017894}, {'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.5235575501288667}])
```

which gives the following dataframe:

```
       area  elev
0  3.523558   0.0
1  3.523558   0.0
```

Then group by the elev columns and sum the area's:

```
desired_output = df.groupby('elev').sum()
```

which gives:

```
              area
elev          
0.0   7.047115
```

If you want you can then output this dataframe back to a dictionary in a useful format using:

```
desired_output.to_dict('index')
```

which returns

```
{0.0: {'area': 7.0471151003078063}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `defaultdict`, you don't need to the `if/else` statement:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [{'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.52355755017894}, {'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.5235575501288667}]

sumdict = defaultdict(float)

for d in mylist:
    sumdict[d['elev']] += d.get('area', 0.0)

print dict(sumdict)
```

Comment: How would I use this method to build the dictionary with {'elev': x, 'total': y}?

Comment: @McLeodx I updated my answer in case of the key 'area' is absent

Comment: @McLeodx: Just add this line at the end: `mytotalslist = [{'elev': key, 'total': value} for key, value in sumdict.items()]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short code sample that puts the relevant sums into a dictionary. It simply iterates over each dictionary in the input list, adding the `area` values to the appropriate `elev` key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

summed_dict = defaultdict(float)
for tup in input_list:
    summed_dict[tup['elev']] += tup['area']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> l = [{'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.52355755017894}, {'elev': 0.0, 'area': 3.5235575501288667}]
>>> added_dict = {}
>>> for i in l:
      if i['elev'] in added_dict:
          added_dict[i['elev']] +=  i['area']
      else:
          added_dict[i['elev']] =  i['area']


>>> added_dict
{0.0: 7.0471151003078063}
```